# Best way to install another stack (phidgets)

Tags: rosmake, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use a phidget interfacekit 8/8/8 with ROS on a Raspberry Pi. **But it's not clear to me what best way to do this is, could someone clearify this or point me to a page with clear information?** Given the limited space on the Pi I don't want to check out an entire svn if possible.

I want to install the phidget library. There are two libraries?

- Footes: https://phidget.foote-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/hg/
- http://ros.org/wiki/phidgets_ros

EDIT: I used the new overlay method but now I still got a problem.
When running: rosrun phidgets_ros interface_kit.py
I got this error: rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: phidgetspp_c_api
The problem is that I can't install the phidgetspp_c_api.
When installing I got an error with the certificate:

```
 Command failed: 'hg clone "https://phidget.foote-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/hg" /home/lennart/fuerte_workspace/phidgetspp_c_api'
 errcode: 255:
abort: phidget.foote-ros-pkg.googlecode.com certificate error: certificate is for *.googlecode.com, *.u.googlecode.com, googlecode.com, *.codespot.com, *.googlesource.com, googlesource.com (use --insecure to connect insecurely)
[/vcstools]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41181/best-way-to-install-another-stack-(phidgets)/) by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2573 on 2012-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wow. You found a really old tutorial :)

Have a look at the [ROS Overlay page](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays), in particular the section about adding stacks using roslocate.

Essentially, to add new stacks you first create an overlay. Then you either create and merge your own rosinstall file that contains the stacks you want to install, use roslocate or check out the stacks manually into a 'sandbox' directory that is in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

**Edit**: I guess the problem is that your computer doesn't know about the required googlecode certificate and rejects to check it out. Try checking it out manually (I assume that you created a sandbox directory as shown on the wiki page):

```
cd ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
hg clone "https://phidget.foote-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/hg" /home/lennart/fuerte_workspace/phidgetspp_c_api
```

After that it should be available in the workspace already.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The certificate error is related to phidget being a subrepository of foote-ros-pkg, which is not covered by the googlecode certificate. The following URL works correctly:

https://code.google.com/p/foote-ros-pkg.phidget/

The indexer should probably be changed to point to this URL instead.

---

Originally posted by [wcaarls](https://answers.ros.org/users/3110/wcaarls/) with karma: 76 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1